# Iterating over lists and summing and putting result in dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose i have two (could be more) lists of same object having same fields/properties.
Each list represent the same object

**Proerpties:**

```
HoursWorked
HoursRate
```

I want to take iterate and take sum of each field from all lists (could be 2, 3, or so on) and store it in an dictionary with key value pair. `e.g HoursWorked:2 and HourseRate:6`

**Currently**, i am able to do it for only one field only (hard coded). I want to make it generic so i can fill dictionary with Key/Value for all fields.

I have defined my dictionary as follow

```
public Dictionary<string, double> TotalCount { get; set; }
```

Linq Query:

```
Dictionary<string, double> totalCount = records
.GroupBy(x => records)
.ToDictionary(x => Convert.ToString("HoursWorked"), x => x.Where(y => y.HoursWorked != null).Sum(y => y.HoursWorked).Value);
```

Any help on this?

**Sample Data**:

```
Input
    report = 
    { 
    [HoursWorked: 1.0, HoursRate:10], 
    [HoursWork:2.0, HoursRate:15]
    }

Expected Output
Dictioary = {Key:HoursWorked Value: 3.0,Key:HoursRate Value:25}
```

Comment: You want "HoursWorked" and "HoursRate" to be your dictionary keys?

Comment: Yes, i want exactly that

Comment: Sample data and expected result please.

Comment: But that doesn't look like a dictionary - you just summed both properties which produces a singe { HoursWorked, HoursRate } pair

Comment: I want to use key value from list and names are not known ... Also there could be 10 lists.. All i want to dynamic what i stated in my question. please first have look at my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, double> dictionary = new[] { "HoursWorked", "HoursRate" }
    .ToDictionary(k => k, v => collections
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .Sum(y => (double)y.GetType().GetProperty(v).GetValue(y)));
```

Where 'collections' is your collection of lists.
Obviously totally type unsafe and will fall down very easily!

I would argue that a much better pattern for this, as opposed to using reflection, would be to write a method or interface that will return the correct double value given the string key.

Answer (score -1):

```
class someObject
    {
        public int workingHours { get; set; }
        public int hourRate { get; set; }
    }
```

You can create a common list from all list.

```
List<SomeObject> lst = new List<SomeObject>();
lst.AddRange(Oldlst1);
lst.AddRange(Oldlst2);
```

Then you can group by based on hour rate.

```
var n = lst.GroupBy(x=>x.hourRate);
```

And then you can create a dictionary.

```
var m=n.ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Sum(y=>y.workingHours));
```

Here in m you will get hourRate and in value you will get sum of working hour.